# How to update a value in array Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a fixed array(9) and I want to update the value of the array, this works perfectly but I want to optimize the code:

```js
constructor (props) {
  super();
  this.state ={
    token: "X",
    val: ["","","","","","","","",""]
  };
}

intelligentComputerPlay () {
  this.setState({
    val: [
      this.state.token,
      this.state.val[1],
      this.state.val[2],
      this.state.val[3],
      this.state.val[4],
      this.state.val[5],  
      this.state.val[6],  
      this.state.val[7],  
      this.state.val[8]
    ];
  });
```

Comment: Could you expand on what is the general goal? This seems like a very wrong approach, but we cannot suggest anything better without knowing the general context.

Comment: By optimize, do you mean make cleaner?

Comment: @KamilSolecki in intelligentComputerPlay () method i just change the first value but i have written all the elements of the list, i need just updates the value that will be changing in the list. Is it possible?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could work.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
     val: [token, ...prevState.val.slice(1, prevState.val.length - 1)]
}));
```

Comment: how to write it if i want to change the third element for example?

Comment: `val: [...prevState.val.slice(0, 3), token, ...prevState.val.slice(5, prevState.val.length - 1)]`